# Custom navigation bar using Xamarin forms with prism broken

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm using Prism Library for Xamarin.Forms.

And I'm going to create custom navigation bar via Control template. (Reason of creating custom navigation bar - I didn't find solution to make navigation bar transparent for display background image, also I will probably customize my navigation bar and add some controls on it).

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="NavigationPageTemplate">
    <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent">

        <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
               Aspect="AspectFill"
               Source="{TemplateBinding BackgroundImageEx}" />

        <ContentView Padding="0,50,0,0"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
            <ContentPresenter />
        </ContentView>

        <!--Navigation bar started here -->
        <ContentView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,AutoSize"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional, WidthProportional"
                     BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <ContentView.Padding>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                            Android="10"
                            iOS="10, 20, 10, 0" />
            </ContentView.Padding>

            <controls:ImageButton Command="{TemplateBinding GoBackCommand}"
                                  HeightRequest="30"
                                  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                                  Source="ic_back.png"
                                  WidthRequest="30">

            </controls:ImageButton>

        </ContentView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And my problem is to process back button press with Prism Navigation.
I've tried to process click on MyApp.xaml.cs file.

```xml
private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.GoBackAsync();
}
```

And it seems to have different navigation stack because it shows after press my first page.

I had Navigation this way:

`Navigate("FirstPage");` -> `Navigate(MasterDetail/NavigationPage/ViewA)` -> `Navigate("ViewB")`
ViewB - uses Control template.

When I click custom back button on ViewB NavigationService back me to FirstPage. It is incorrect for me. I should back to ViewA!

Another question Should first page be saved when we change App.MainPage?

Answer (score 1):

See the discussion of described problem on https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1262

Answer (score 0):

To navigate back from ViewA to FirstPage you can intercept the back event and go back again if a variable is passed with a specific value from the ViewB page. Code Example:

Sender:

```
var navigationParams = new NavigationParameters();
navigationParams.Add("yourVariableName", "YourVariableValue");
_navigationService.GoBackAsync(navigationParams);
```

Receiver:

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
        {
  string myVar = null;
            if (parameters.ContainsKey("yourVariableName"))
            {
                myVar = (string)parameters["yourVariableName"];
            }
  if(myVar=="YourVariableValue"){
     NavigationService.GoBackAsync();
  }
}
```

I don't understand your second question.

Comment: The second question why my FirstPage are still on memory and it haven't been removed from NavigationStack?

Comment: I think it's ok because it's a stack, so it's a LIFO (last in - first out). You can't remove the FirstPage, the only way to remove it is remove all the pages because it's the first putted in the stack, so the last that will exit.